# Will a header() call written via document.write initiate a javascript onload function?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, header

If I send a header() using PHP to javascript via AJAX which then writes the output using document.write, will that initiate the javascript onload function if document.write writes the entire page?  I need it to initiate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The real question is whether `document.write` after the initial DOM has loaded will re-call the document's `onLoad` function.

[It's trivially testable, and the answer is "no"](http://jsfiddle.net/kK4hp/):

```
$(function() {
    document.write("lol");
    // ^ interestingly, `console` doesn't appear to exist after this

    alert("onload"); // only happens once
});
```

Answer (score 0):

No it wont. However you should prevent outputing/executing script after you call `header("Location: something.php");`

You can prevent it with

```
die();
```

Comment: Problem is, I need the onload function to initiate, currently it is not.